# I want to make my project run in other browser

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I create a new project using laravel 5.8, and it is running on localhost:8080. How can I make it running on other url e.g https://swap.maximine.io.test?

Comment: Buy that domain and have it pointing to the IP of the server your site is hosted on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we need some extra information how you created the project and how you want to run the project.

But you can change the port where the application is running on by using:

```
php artisan serve --port=80
```

To use that domain, do you own this domain? Or do you want to use it locally?
You can add the domain to you hostfile pointing to you localhost and use it as an test environment